# get id of first child of class and then trigger onclick event of that

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am dynamicaly creating html as below,

```
<div id="disc_cat">
<ul class="viewCatList">
<img id="prod1" src="../products/ `Image_url`" class="slide_contain" onclick="getCanvas(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,' `Image_url`')">
<img id="prod3" src="../products/ `Image_url`" class="slide_contain" onclick="getCanvas(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,' `Image_url`')">
</ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to trigger click event of first image , but i dont know the id.

I tried ,

```
$( "ul.viewCatList" ).find("img:first").attr("id"));
```

and many things , what is the correct way to get id of first child in `viewCatList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want the `id`, once you have the jQuery wrapper for the element just call the `click()` on that

```
$( "ul.viewCatList" ).find("img:first").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will get you the first id of image and then you can use along with # for click event..Comment here for further queries

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var x=$( "ul.viewCatList" ).find("img:first").attr("id");
alert(x);
$("#"+x).click(function(){
   // do your stuff here..
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "ul.viewCatList" ).find("img:first").attr("id"));
```

is working fine. It gives your the ID "prod1" of first image element.

But as you know, that click event is bind on jquery element object. So you can directly call click event on `$( "ul.viewCatList" ).find("img:first")` like below.

```
 $( "ul.viewCatList" ).find("img:first").click(function(){
      console.log("Here is your image1")
})
```